# Can i used different Database on remote server for civicrm logging?

Tags: drupal, civicrm.settings.php

Is it possible? Used the different database on remote server for civicrm logging.
Means: Currently i am using two databases one for drupal and second is using for Civicrm. Both are on different remote server.  Now i want to create a third server for civicrm logging database. It is showing error "DB Error: no such database". I already configured in civicrm.settings.php file.
define('CIVICRM_LOGGING_DSN',mysql://myserverdetail);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parvez is right that you can use a different DATABASE but if you mean a different HOST then the answer is no. The triggers that are used don't support that.

Comment: Yeah I was thinking about that but as you pointed out if the triggers themselves don't allow a different host but there are workarounds to this at the MariaDB/MySQL layer if you really wanted to do it. It would need a patch to the code that generates the logging tables - something along these lines https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26503342/how-to-create-trigger-to-insert-data-to-a-database-on-another-server

Comment: Ah cool. Didn't know you could create tables like that.

Answer (score 2):

Yes perfectly possible, we do it all the time. You can set the logging DSN in your settings file (CIVICRM_LOGGING_DSN) if its not set then CiviCRM falls back to the CIVICRM_DSN

Sorry - just read your whole question!

I would check that the user has permissions from the CIVICRM_DSN to the CIVICRM_LOGGING_DSN i.e. if the CiviCRM database user cannot access the logging database then maybe thats causing the issue.